# layout overrides working on development server but not on production server

Tags: overrides

I did a backup (using akeeba) on the development server then used akeeba kickstart to restore from that backup on the production server. Everything from that restoration seems to be working fine, except for layout overrides. I had previously done a from scratch install of Joomla, installed the template, and it's the same results. Layout overrides aren't working.

Both instances are Joomla version 3.8.5

All the Joomla settings for layout override are the same (selected layout on article options) both articles in question have menu items with the same exact settings (also tried it without menu items for these articles), and the layout override files are in place in both instances.

Does anyone have any idea why layout override isn't working on the production server?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The issue was caused by capitol letters in the override file names.

I presume some setting on the production server is different than on dev server though because it's the same Joomla.